# As3 & Flex Builder: Flickr API Photo Application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, api, flickr, flash-builder

My problem is when I run the application, the photos show up fine, but they pop up only in a single row. I'm trying to get at least 20 rows on the application. Also, how would I code the button function (searchNow) to take whatever tags that is entered inside of the search bar to display the right images?

```
{
//===================
//ini variables
//===================
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.text.TextField;

import libs.flickrviewer_mc;

Security.allowDomain("*", "api.flickr.com");
import flash.display.Bitmap;

public class FlickrViewer extends libs.flickrviewer_mc
{
    //===================
    //ini variables
    //===================
    private var tag:String;

    //===================
    //ini variables
    //===================
    private var xpos:Number = 0;
    private var ypos:Number = 0;
    private var dif:Number = 150;
    private var totalCols:int = 10;
    private var count:int = 0;
    private var i:int = 0;
    private var squares_arr:Array = [];

    //===================
    //flickr variables
    //===================
    private var key:String = "Key Goes Here"; //your flickr api key
    private var per_page:int = 5;
    private var page:int = 1;
    private var xml_url:String = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key="+key+"&tags="+tag+"&per_page="+per_page+"&page="+page;


    //===================
    //XML
    //===================
    private var pics:XML = new XML();
    private var pics_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xml_url);
    private var picsLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(pics_url);

    //===================
    //flickr variables
    //===================
    private var photo_id:String;
    private var photo_owner:String;
    private var photo_url:String = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/";

    public function FlickrViewer()
    {
        super();

        trace("yo");
        this.picsLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, picsLoaded);
        this.back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);
        this.searchFlickr_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, searchNow);
        //this.buttonMode = true;
    }

    private function searchNow(e:Event):void
    {
        var url:String = photo_url+"/"+photo_owner+"/"+photo_id;
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        (req, "_blank");

    }

    private function loadImage(img_src:String):void
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        var img_url:String = img_src;
        var request_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(img_url);
        loader.load(request_url);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressListener);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeListener);
    }

    private function progressListener(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        var bl:int = e.bytesLoaded;
        var bt:int = e.bytesTotal;
        var percent:int = Math.ceil((bl*100)/bt);
    }

    private function completeListener(e:Event):void
    {
        var img:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.content;
        trace(img.width);
        img.x=34 + (count * 90);
        img.y=110;
        img.width = img.height = 75;
        this.addChild(img);
        count++;
    }

    private function picsLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        pics = XML(picsLoader.data);

        var stat:String = pics.@stat.toString();
        var totalPages:int = pics.photos.@pages;
        var totalPics:int = pics.photos.@total;

        trace("bob",pics);
        trace("status: "+stat);
        trace("Total pages: "+totalPages);
        trace("Total pics: "+totalPics);
        trace("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");


        var allPics:XMLList = pics.photos.*;
        //loadImage(allPics[0]);
        for each (var photo:XML in allPics)
        {
            var pic_src:String = "http://farm"+photo.@farm+".static.flickr.com/"+photo.@server+"/"+photo.@id+"_"+photo.@secret+"_m.jpg";

            trace("title: "+photo.@title+" owner: "+photo.@owner);
            trace("Source: "+pic_src);
            trace("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");

            trace(pic_src)
            var newName:String = "square_"+i;

            loadImage(pic_src);


        }

    }

    //===================
    //back button event
    //===================
    private function goBack(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: i suggest you create a new question for your secondary question about the button - its a completely separate subject

Comment: Within the current context it seems you'll need to do this yourself by modifying the x and y properties of the loaded images, alternatively you can use a Group with a TileLayout and allow it to handle the layout of the images.